# How to get parts of an boolean logical expression/ math expression in sympy?

Tags: python, boolean, logic, sympy

I would like to get all the parts of a boolean logic expression like this (x & y) | (a | b). I would like to get (x & y) and (a | b) as separated functions. I tried to use args, but it delivered me (x & y, a,b). I tried use atoms() but it just delivers me {a, x, y, b}. Even iteration through the args as a list didnt give me the wanting result.
I want to get an expression such as (x & y) | (a | b), separate it into parts to create a truth table showing step by step what (x & y) and (a | b) evaluates in between before showing the final results of the expression.

Thank you

Comment: The [atoms](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.atoms) were not a sufficiently detailed representation, ok. [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) your call to [parse_expr()](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html), please, plus the results that come back.

Comment: a = "(a|~b)|(x&y)"
b = parse_expr(a)

Comment: I meant, there's a tree that comes back, in `b`. Did you find anything helpful for your use case in that tree?

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any way to create a nested `Or`, so your expression automatically becomes `(x & y | a | b)` and that is why you get the args you do. I would just create those two expressions in addition to the desired `Or` having them as arguments:

```py
o1 = x & y
o2 = a | b
eq = o1 | o2
from sympy.utilities.iterables import *
for i in subsets((True, False), 4, repetition=True):
    for p in multiset_permutations(i):
        reps = dict(zip((x,y,a,b),p))
        print(reps, o1.xreplace(reps), o2.xreplace(reps), eq.xreplace(reps))
```